# Flyway migration progress

Tags: flyway

Is there a way to get the current status / progress of a migration? We are currently building a UI for flyway and we are having difficulties managing a progress bar.

flyway.migrate only return how many successful update were processed.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to hook into this.

Please file an enhancement request in [the issue tracker](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues).

Comment: Issue 512: Flyway migration progress enhancement

Comment: @xam7766 Perhaps you meant issue 506 (not 512): [Flyway migration progress enhancement](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/506)